# Rails.application.routes list all routes and determine controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to write a script that can list all available routes and for each route, query the controller and action name (a bit like rake routes).

If I run `Rails.application.routes.routes` I can see the data is all there. I just can't seem to access it.

```
 @named_routes=
  {"root"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x007fc2cb40a598
     @app=
      #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher:0x007fc2cb40b448
       @controller_class_names=#<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x007fc2cb40b420 @backend={}, @default_proc=nil>,
       @defaults={:trailing_slash=>false, :controller=>"home", :action=>"show"},
       @glob_param=nil>,
     @constraints={:required_defaults=>[:trailing_slash, :controller, :action], :request_method=>/^GET$/},
     @decorated_ast=nil,
     @defaults={:trailing_slash=>false, :controller=>"home", :action=>"show"},
```

How do I access that hash tucked away in there with the controller name.

As a side, Is there a way to determine a path from this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work if I understand your question correctly:

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.named_routes.values.map(&:defaults)
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.named_routes.values.map do |route|
  "#{route.defaults[:controller]}#{route.defaults[:action]}"
end
```

Comment: thank you my man, that worked a treat, minus the slight typo ;)

Comment: For rails 5 it has slightly changed. I used this to get all routes
`Rails.application.routes.named_routes.send(:routes).values`